# how to set a parameter error in procedure or function in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

so here I'm creating a web app which using sql server database connection, here i have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spMSTransaction_Insert] 
    @OrgID int,
    @SiteID int,
    @TransactionCategoryID int,
    @TransactionDesc varchar(300),
    @IsActive bit,
    @CreatedDate datetime,
    @CreatedBy varchar(50),
    @ModifiedDate datetime,
    @ModifiedBy varchar(50)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MSTransaction] 
(
    [OrgID], 
    [SiteID], 
    [TransactionCategoryID], 
    [TransactionDesc], 
    [IsActive], 
    [CreatedDate], 
    [CreatedBy], 
    [ModifiedDate], 
    [ModifiedBy]
)
SELECT  @OrgID, 
        @SiteID, 
        @TransactionCategoryID, 
        @TransactionDesc, 
        @IsActive, 
        @CreatedDate, 
        @CreatedBy, 
        @ModifiedDate, 
        @ModifiedBy

COMMIT
```

and in the code behind i have this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logID = Helper.GetLogID();
    try
    {
        LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "btnSave_Click", "Start Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
        orgID = 1;
        siteID = 1;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfOrgID.Value))
        {
            clsTransaction.InsertTransaction(Helper.LogID, Helper.OrgID, Helper.SiteID, 
                CommonFunctions.StringToInt(ddlTransactionCategory.SelectedValue), txtTransactionDesc.Text, true);
        }
        else
        {
            int transactionID = CommonFunctions.StringToInt(hfOrgID.Value);
            clsTransaction.UpdateTransaction(logID, orgID, siteID, 1,
                CommonFunctions.StringToInt(ddlTransactionCategory.SelectedValue), txtTransactionDesc.Text, true);
        }

        string message = string.Format(Constants.SaveMessage, "Transaction");
        LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "btnSave_Click", "End Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Info", "alert('" + message + "');window.location ='Transaction.aspx';", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "btnSave_Click", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, Helper.GetUserName());
        throw;
    }
}
```

and the class is as below:

```
public static void InsertTransaction(decimal logID, int orgID, int siteID, int TransactionCategoryID, string TransactionDesc, bool isActive)
{
    LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "InsertTransaction", "Start Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetAppDBConnection(Constants.AppID, Constants.TMDDBConnection)))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "spMSTransaction_Insert";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("orgID", orgID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("siteID", siteID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TransactionCategoryID", TransactionCategoryID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TransactionDesc", TransactionDesc));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IsActive", siteID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", Helper.GetUserName()));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "InsertTransaction", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, Helper.GetUserName());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "InsertTransaction", "End Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
}
```

but when i tried to insert the data, the error pointed to

> Procedure or function 'spMSTransaction_Insert' expects parameter '@CreatedDate', which was not supplied.

and the error line is (which line 73 is marked red):

```
Line 71: {
Line 72:     LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "InsertTransaction", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, Helper.GetUserName());
Line 73:     throw;
Line 74: }
Line 75: finally
```

i'm confused, what's the mistake, any suggestion of what i'm missing here?

Comment: The problem is exact what the error said. You must supply to the cmd all the procedure parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are missing a parameter for the stored procedure, to be specific`@CreatedDate`

You need to add:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CreatedDate", DateTime.Now));
```

Note: You will have to supply all of the other parameters that you are missing or you will encounter the same error.

Comment: @kostasch - true, however I'm going from what the error message states.  Hopefully this will guide them in the correct direction so he can supply the other arguments himself.

Comment: You r right :).But @AdamMaras's answer was solving totally the problem. So i believe must take more ++ than yor answer :) , which is absolutely right.

Comment: i hope i can make you both the answer, but since @DarrenDavies answered first, i give my vote to you, sir

Answer (score 1):

The exception text is pretty clear:

> Procedure or function 'spMSTransaction_Insert' **expects parameter '@CreatedDate'**, which was **not supplied**.

Your stored procedure expects these parameters that you don't supply...

```
@CreatedDate datetime,
@CreatedBy varchar(50),
@ModifiedDate datetime,
@ModifiedBy varchar(50)
```

...and you're passing a parameter it doesn't expect.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", Helper.GetUserName()));
```

Comment: i hope i can make you both the answer, but since @DarrenDavies answered first, i give my vote to him, thank you sir